# Bound mismatch: The type MyClass1 is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparator<T>> of the type Person<T>

Tags: java, generics

I get an error:::Bound mismatch: The type MyClass1 is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparator<T>> of the type Person<T>`

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person<MyClass1> person2 = new Person<>(); // Bound mismatch: The type MyClass1 is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparator<T>> of the type Person<T>
    }
}



class MyClass1<T extends Comparator<T>> implements Comparator<T>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}



class Person<T extends Comparator<T>>
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is that `MyClass1` needs to match `T extends Comparator<T>`.

For this to be the case, its declaration should be `class MyClass1 extends Comparator<MyClass1>`.

Comment: class MyClass1 extends Comparator<MyClass1> .  i want used type parameter in Comparator interface  no type argument passing